# one-column abstract is moved to next page when I use tcolorbox

Tags: pdftex, tcolorbox, mdframed, abstract, colorbox

I'm making a two-column document, but I need a one-column abstract with background-color for that I am using tcolorbox, if the content of the abstract is too long then the abstract content is moved to the next page, if I am not using the "tcolorbox", then it's working. any alternative way?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{geometry,graphicx,xcolor,enumitem,amsmath,caption}
\definecolor{Cgreen}{RGB}{41,106,48}%LIGHT
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
%\usepackage{long2}
\makeatletter
%%
%% This is file `long2.sty'.
%%
%% Author: Tomas "tohecz" Hejda <tohecz@gmail.com>
%%
%% Licenced under LaTeX-Project Public License version 1.3 or newer.
%% 
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{long2}[2012/08/19 v0.1 long2: breakable one-column preamble in a two-column document]
​
\newlength\longtwo@top
\newlength\longtwo@bottom
​
\newsavebox\longtwo@box
\def\longtwo@repeat{%
    \longtwo@column[{\@twocolumnfalse
    \ifdim\ht\longtwo@box>1.00\textheight%1
      \begingroup
      \vbadness10000
      \setbox0\vsplit\longtwo@box to 1.00\textheight%1
      \setbox1\vbox{\unvbox\longtwo@box}
      \global\setbox\longtwo@box\vbox{\unvbox1}
      \setbox2\vbox to \textheight{%
        \unvbox0
      }
      \ht2=0.9\textheight
      \box2
      \endgroup
    \else
      \ifdim\ht\longtwo@box>0.84\textheight
        \global\let\longtwo@repeat\clearpage
      \else
        \global\let\longtwo@repeat\relax
      \fi
      \unvbox\longtwo@box
      \vspace{15pt plus 15pt}
    \fi
    }]%
  \longtwo@repeat
}
​
\long\def\longtwo@[#1]{%
  \begingroup
    \let\longtwo@column\twocolumn
    \let\longtwo@mkttl\maketitle
    \def\maketitle{
      \begingroup
      \let\newpage\relax
      \longtwo@mkttl
      \endgroup
    }
    \longtwo@column[{\@twocolumnfalse
    \global\setbox\longtwo@box\vbox{#1}%
    \ifdim\ht\longtwo@box>\textheight
      \begingroup
      \vbadness10000
      \setbox0\vsplit\longtwo@box to 1.00\textheight%1
      \setbox1\vbox{\unvbox\longtwo@box}%
      \global\setbox\longtwo@box\vbox{\unvbox1}%
      \setbox2\vbox to \textheight{%
        \unvbox0
      }
      \ht2=0.9\textheight
      \box2
      \endgroup
    \else
      \ifdim\ht\longtwo@box>0.87\textheight
        \global\let\longtwo@repeat\clearpage
      \else
        \global\let\longtwo@repeat\relax
      \fi
      \unvbox\longtwo@box
    \fi
    }]%
    \longtwo@repeat
  \endgroup
}
​
\def\longtwocolumn{\@ifnextchar[\longtwo@\twocolumn}
​
%\endinput
%%
%% End of file `long2.sty'.
%%
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\parskip0pt plus 8pt
​
\title{My title}
\author{My the first}
​
\begin{document}
​
\longtwocolumn[{\maketitle
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,
breakable,
size=title,
sharp corners,
rounded corners=northeast,
rounded corners=northwest,
colback=Cgreen!25!white,
colframe=Cgreen,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
titlerule=1mm,
titlerule style=black,
title={\center Key Messages
},
pad at break=2mm,
break at=-\baselineskip/0pt,
height fixed for=middle]
​
\begin{abstract}
​
\lipsum[1-18]
\end{abstract}
\end{tcolorbox}    
%\lipsum[9-15]
}]
​
\lipsum[16-25]
​
\end{document}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem or I don't understand what the problem is. If I compile the above code (either with or without commenting out the line directly following the `tcolorbox`), the following text, be it the one-columns abstract or the regular two-column text, starts directly after the `tcolorbox` on the same page.

Comment: @Jasper Habicht please have look at the first page, it's becomes empty when I use tcolorbox

Comment: I see, you mean the page break before the `tcolorbox`. By the way, there seem to be some invisible characters in the code you posted (zero width spaces). You may want to remove them (but they are not the source of the problem).

Comment: I updated my answer. It seems that the `tcolorbox` behaves as if it still were in a two-column environment. So you need to set the box height explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that a `tcolorbox` that is placed in a single-column environment, which again is embedded in a two-column context, still behaves as if it were in a two-column environment. Hence, you need to tell it exactly where to break. You can do this using the `break at` option and state the size of the box on the first page explicitly.

For example `break at=15cm/0pt` means that the first part of the breakable box (that is the part directly following the title) should have a size of 15cm (which seems to be about the size of the space below the title) and the following boxes should be as large as possible. (You had something similar in your code already.)

Sadly, if you decide to make the title larger (by adding more lines), you need to adjust this explicit statement.

The following seems to work (although there seem to be smaller alignment issues):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{geometry,graphicx,xcolor,enumitem,amsmath,caption}

\definecolor{Cgreen}{RGB}{41,106,48}%LIGHT
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{filecontents}{long2.sty}
%%
%% This is file `long2.sty'.
%%
%% Author: Tomas "tohecz" Hejda <tohecz@gmail.com>
%%
%% Licenced under LaTeX-Project Public License version 1.3 or newer.
%% 
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{long2}[2012/08/19 v0.1 long2: breakable one-column preamble in a two-column document]

\newlength\longtwo@top
\newlength\longtwo@bottom

\newsavebox\longtwo@box
\def\longtwo@repeat{%
    \longtwo@column[{\@twocolumnfalse
    \ifdim\ht\longtwo@box>1.00\textheight%1
      \begingroup
      \vbadness10000
      \setbox0\vsplit\longtwo@box to 1.00\textheight%1
      \setbox1\vbox{\unvbox\longtwo@box}
      \global\setbox\longtwo@box\vbox{\unvbox1}
      \setbox2\vbox to \textheight{%
        \unvbox0
      }
      \ht2=0.9\textheight
      \box2
      \endgroup
    \else
      \ifdim\ht\longtwo@box>0.84\textheight
        \global\let\longtwo@repeat\clearpage
      \else
        \global\let\longtwo@repeat\relax
      \fi
      \unvbox\longtwo@box
      \vspace{15pt plus 15pt}
    \fi
    }]%
  \longtwo@repeat
}

\long\def\longtwo@[#1]{%
  \begingroup
    \let\longtwo@column\twocolumn
    \let\longtwo@mkttl\maketitle
    \def\maketitle{
      \begingroup
      \let\newpage\relax
      \longtwo@mkttl
      \endgroup
    }
    \longtwo@column[{\@twocolumnfalse
    \global\setbox\longtwo@box\vbox{#1}%
    \ifdim\ht\longtwo@box>\textheight
      \begingroup
      \vbadness10000
      \setbox0\vsplit\longtwo@box to 1.00\textheight%1
      \setbox1\vbox{\unvbox\longtwo@box}%
      \global\setbox\longtwo@box\vbox{\unvbox1}%
      \setbox2\vbox to \textheight{%
        \unvbox0
      }
      \ht2=0.9\textheight
      \box2
      \endgroup
    \else
      \ifdim\ht\longtwo@box>0.87\textheight
        \global\let\longtwo@repeat\clearpage
      \else
        \global\let\longtwo@repeat\relax
      \fi
      \unvbox\longtwo@box
    \fi
    }]%
    \longtwo@repeat
  \endgroup
}

\def\longtwocolumn{\@ifnextchar[\longtwo@\twocolumn}

%\endinput
%%
%% End of file `long2.sty'.
%%
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{long2}

\parskip0pt plus 8pt

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{My title}
\author{My the first}

\begin{document}
\longtwocolumn[{%
\maketitle
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw, 
breakable,
break at=15cm/0pt,                     % <-- !
size=title,
sharp corners,
rounded corners=northeast,
rounded corners=northwest,
colback=Cgreen!25!white,
colframe=Cgreen,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
titlerule=1mm,
titlerule style=black,
title={\center Key Messages},
pad at break=2mm]

\lipsum[1-16]

\end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum[5-10]
}]

\lipsum[16-25]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

However, you should also consider to use the `multicol` package and wrap the body text in a two-column environment. This may be a bit easier.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,graphicx,xcolor,enumitem,amsmath,caption}

\definecolor{Cgreen}{RGB}{41,106,48}%LIGHT
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{multicol}
\parskip0pt plus 8pt

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{My title}
\author{My the first}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw, 
breakable, 
size=title,
sharp corners,
rounded corners=northeast,
rounded corners=northwest,
colback=Cgreen!25!white,
colframe=Cgreen,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
titlerule=1mm,
titlerule style=black,
title={\center Key Messages},
pad at break=2mm]

\lipsum[1-6]

\end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum[5-10]

\begin{multicols}{2}%
\lipsum[16-25]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]